# Unity UI navigation with controller on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gamepad

I have a UI canvas in my scene with an EventSystem where the Standalone Input Module is attached. On PC I can navigate through the main menu with a Xbox gamepad. On android (with an android gamepad) it doesn't work. When I start the game the android gamepad works fine, but it doesn't work with the UI menu. What am I missing?